# C# - Switch Enum - Type name ' ' does not exist in the type ' '

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I am getting an error "The type name 'Home' does not exist in the type 'MenuEnum'" when using it in a switch case.  If I just go a if statement it works without issue.

The issue is when I use the MenuEnum.Home I am getting a IDE error and my code will not compile.

I also switched to a regular switch statement below in the code example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Added Code below***

```
public void Selected(MenuEventArgs<MenuItem> args)
{
    //The ULR to navigate to
    var url = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        //If there is no data do nothing
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Item.Text))
            return;
            
        //switch on the incoming text
        switch (args.Item.Text)
        {
            //IDE Error on home (will not compile)...
            case MenuEnum.Home.ToString():
                url = "/";
                break;
            default:
                url = "";
                break;
        }

        //working code
        if (args.Item.Text == MenuEnum.Home.ToString().Replace('_', ' '))
        {
            url = "/";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    
    Navigation.NavigateTo(url);  
}
```

/*-Enum file-*/

```
 namespace ManagerDashboard2022.Client.ENUMs;

 /// <summary>
 /// The Items in the menu
 /// </summary>
 public enum MenuEnum
 {
     Home
 }
```

Comment: Please, share code, not images.

Comment: You are using C#9.0 switch relational pattern but [it should compare an expression result with a constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#relational-patterns). The ````ToString()```` call makes this wrong.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I have added Code as requested.

Comment: @cly I changed to a traditionally switch case with the same result.  I added the code with the traditionally switch, but the same error.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I added the screen shot as requested, but the error was in the questions text.  "The type name 'Home' does not exist in the type 'MenuEnum'"

Comment: as @cly notes in their comment, you need to remove `.ToString()`, because switch requires a constant.  try `case "anEnumName":` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to switch on string values, you can replace that

```
 case MenuEnum.Home.ToString():
```

with

```
 case nameof(MenuEnum.Home):
```

`nameof` is evaluated at compile time to result in the string constant "Home" (in this case). As this is a *constant*, you can "switch" on it.

The advantage of using nameof instead of just the string "Home" is that with nameof the MenuEnum.Home value needs to exist - so you get an compiler error on typos.

That error message you got:

> "The type name 'Home' does not exist in the type 'MenuEnum'"

is not very helpful in this case. It should have been (IMO) something like "you cannot have a runtime expression as case label".

Comment: That's all the point: the compiler message is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @cly.

I needed to parse the enum and switch on that returned item

```
public void Selected(MenuEventArgs<MenuItem> args)
{
    //The ULR to navigate to
    var url = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        //If there is no data do nothing
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Item.Text))
            return;

        //convert text to enum
        var menuItem = Enum.Parse<MenuEnum>(args.Item.Text);
            
        //switch enum
        url = menuItem switch
        {
            MenuEnum.Home => "/",
            _ => ""

        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    
    Navigation.NavigateTo(url);  
}
```

Comment: You will meet problems if ````args.Item.Text```` value is not parseable as ````MenuEnum````. Use ````Enum.TryParse```` instead and handle the unparsable value case.

Comment: @cly Correct, and yes I already made the change.  I just wanted to test it really quickly, but updated to a Enum.TryParse when I added my other menu items.  All of this because I don't like magic strings...lol.  Thanks again for the help.